# cannot boot into windows 8 after installing kali

Tags: bootrepair

have windows 8 in my hard disk and i installed Kali on a pen drive disk(not live). after installing i could not boot into windows i un-installed Kali but grub is still my boot loader and it does not detect windows 8.. i have already tried boot-repair but still could not solve the problem , they gave me this link http://paste.ubuntu.com/9582142/ which has boot info of my PC..please help i am a newbie and struggling from many days

Comment: Did you try Sytem Restore using the repair disc?

Answer (score 1):

sda is apparently your HD? It looks like it's allmost all formated as ext4 (linux) with Kali GNU/Linux 1.0.9, plus a small linux swap partition. And sdb is an 8GB (probably usb) drive with Ubuntu (syslinux) on it?

Do you have another HD with windows on it? Or if sda is your only HD, Windows would never install to an ext4 filesystem, it appears that if windows was ever on sda, **it's gone now**.

There's a chance you may be able to **recover** some of the files that used to be on the HD with a tool like `testdisk` or `photorec`, maybe even recover some partitions, but I'd guess that Kali overwrote a significant portion of Windows. - Unless there was a windows recovery partition at the start of the drive and only that was overwritten by Kali, then the "real" windows partition *might* be mostly there still.

## Relevant pasted info:

sda1: __________________________________________________________________________

```
File system:       ext4
Boot sector type:  -
Boot sector info: 
Operating System:  Kali GNU/Linux 1.0.9 
Boot files:        /boot/grub/grub.cfg /etc/fstab 
                   /boot/extlinux/extlinux.conf /boot/grub/core.img
```

sdb1: __________________________________________________________________________

```
File system:       vfat
Boot sector type:  SYSLINUX 6.03 20140721... :..(:,:0:4:8:....D:H:L:C.T:C.\:`:d:C.l:p:t:x:|:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.............
Boot sector info:  Syslinux looks at sector 1325354 of /dev/sdb1 for its 
                   second stage. SYSLINUX is installed in the  directory. 
                   No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
Operating System:  
Boot files:        /boot/grub/grub.cfg /syslinux.cfg /casper/vmlinuz.efi 
                   /EFI/BOOT/grubx64.efi /ldlinux.sys
```

---

```
Disk /dev/sda: 320.1 GB, 320072933376 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 38913 cylinders, total 625142448 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes

Partition  Boot  Start Sector    End Sector  # of Sectors  Id System

/dev/sda1    *          2,048   609,277,951   609,275,904  83 Linux
/dev/sda2         609,279,998   625,141,759    15,861,762   5 Extended
/dev/sda5         609,280,000   625,141,759    15,861,760  82 Linux swap / Solaris
```

---

```
Model: ATA WDC WD3200BPVT-2 (scsi)
Disk /dev/sda: 320GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/4096B
Partition Table: msdos

Number  Start   End    Size    Type      File system     Flags
1      1049kB  312GB  312GB   primary   ext4            boot
2      312GB   320GB  8121MB  extended
5      312GB   320GB  8121MB  logical   linux-swap(v1)
```

---

```
Model: Sony Storage Media (scsi)
Disk /dev/sdb: 7774MB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: msdos

Number  Start   End     Size    Type     File system  Flags
1      32.8kB  2988MB  2988MB  primary  fat32        boot
2      2988MB  3053MB  64.9MB  primary  fat16
3      3053MB  7773MB  4720MB  primary  fat32
```

Answer (score 0):

For windows boot go trough sequence BIOS -> MBR (Master Boot Record on HDD) -> Partition Boot record -> BCD -> OS

GRUB usually installed in MBR, or in Partition boot, so You beed to restore MBR and partition boot record to eliminate GRUB and restore Windows boot.

Try this procedures to restore (https://neosmart.net/wiki/fix-mbr/#Fix_the_MBR_in_Windows_8_or_81)

If You alrerady tried "bootrec /FixBoot" ensure You do "bootrec /FixMbr"

```
Boot from the original installation DVD (or the recovery USB)
At the Welcome screen, click Repair your computer

Windows 8 Repair Your Computer Menu
Choose Troubleshoot
Choose Command Prompt
When the Command Prompt loads, type the following commands:

bootrec /FixMbr
bootrec /FixBoot
bootrec /ScanOs
bootrec /RebuildBcd

Press Enter after each command and wait for each operation to finish
Remove the DVD from the disk tray
Type exit
Hit Enter
Restart your computer and check if Windows 8/8.1 can now boot

If bootrec utility doesn’t fix your Windows 8/8.1, try following the next commands to fix the EFI bootloader of the Windows 8/8.1:

Boot from the installation DVD or the Windows 8 or Windows 8.1 recovery USB
Click Repair your computer
Choose Troubleshoot
Choose Command Prompt
Type these commands in order and hit Enter after each:

diskpart
sel disk 0
list vol

These commands will select the first disk of your computer and the list all the partitions available on that disk.
Check for the volume item that has the Fs column FAT32. The EFI partition must be formatted under FAT32.
If the volume number of EFI partition is “2”, type the following command:

sel vol 2

If the volume number is different than 2, replace “2” with the number available on your computer.
Assign a letter to this partition, a letter that is different that those already available on your computer, for example x:\. Type this command to assign the letter:

assign letter=x:

Wait for the success message to appear:

DiskPart successfully assigned the drive letter or mount point.

Type exit to quit the DiskPart utility:

exit

Type this command and replace x:\ with the letter you assigned earlier to the EFI partition:

cd /d x:\EFI\Microsoft\Boot\

Then type the bootrec command to repair the volume:

bootrec /fixboot

Now you need to backup the old BCD and recreate a new one. Type:

ren BCD BCD.backup

Type this command to recreate the BCD and replace the x:\ with the assigned letter earlier:

bcdboot c:\Windows /l en-us /s x: /f ALL

In above command, Windows is installed on c:\. If the drive letter where your Windows 8/8.1 is installed is different, replace c:\ with your drive letter.
Remove the DVD from the disk tray
Type exit
Restart your computer
```

"bootrec /FixMbr" and "bootrec /FixBoot" definitely replace GRUB by Windows boot records and enough for win 7 and older, but I dont hawe much expirience with EFI.

Upd.

I look at Your botinfo. Look like there no windows partition, ntfs or FAT32 on HDD  (sda). You installed Kali on hdd and format it.